# SQL Server stored procedure query to return multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geospatial

The following query returns 4 columns, but if I attempt to return the same from a stored procedure I get

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

If I want to get the values returned in a comma delimited string how do I write it?

Working query

```
Declare @g geography = 'POINT(-1.2846387 52.686091)'  

Select top 1 
    Round(Geocolumn.STDistance(@g)/1000, 2) as DistanceInKlms,
    Registration, location, dateoffix  
from 
    Positions  
where
    Geocolumn.STDistance(@g) is not null
    and Registration = 'DX17AAF'
order by
    Geocolumn.STDistance(@g);
```

Stored procedure breaks because of multiple columns:

```
select @return =    (Select Top(1)
          Round(GeographyPositon.STDistance(@g)/1000, 2) as DistanceInKlms,
          Registration, [location], dateoffix  
from Positions 
WHERE   Registration = @Registration
ORDER BY GeographyPositon.STDistance(@g))
```

Comment: You need to convert `@return` to a table variable so that you can return row(s) instead of a single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you need that?

```
select @return =    (Select Top(1)
          Round(GeographyPositon.STDistance(@g)/1000, 2)+' , '
          Registration+' , '+ [location] +' , '+ dateoffix  
from Positions 
WHERE   Registration = @Registration
ORDER BY GeographyPositon.STDistance(@g)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your query I had done a work around by declaring three variables to hold the the results of the query and then concatenating the results into the @results parameter.  Not as eloquent  as your method!

Answer (score 0):

Try below to get all 4 column values in a single string.

```
select @return =    ( Select Top(1)
          CAST(Round(GeographyPositon.STDistance(@g)/1000, 2) AS VARCHAR)+', '
          CAST(Registration AS VARCHAR)+', '+ CAST([location] AS VARCHAR) +', '+ CAST(dateoffix AS VARCHAR)
from Positions 
WHERE   Registration = @Registration
ORDER BY GeographyPositon.STDistance(@g) )
```